# VisualStudio 2017 Console Project template missing

Tags: c#, console-application, visual-studio-2017

Yes, i've tried devenv/install, with no help.
So, I don't have the Console C# Project option when creating the project, 
[as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaKyI.png)
Currently i have installed windows basic pack  - there's my ['about' screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7I0U.png).

I have just reinstalled Windows because i was getting the same exact problem on old system, and because VS2015 had interface bugs and crashed consequently, but it didn`t help(as well as reinstalling both VS 2015 and 2017 numerous times)
Hope that you can guess whats wrong with my PC.

Comment: How did you install VS2017? Which workloads and/or components did you select? Looks like you're missing ".NET desktop development".

Comment: When it came to (keyboard) settings did you choose General, c#, VB or did choose Tester or ProjMgr instead? If the latter some templates are missing. Pretty sure a devenv.exe /resetsettings allows you to change it

Comment: I think CodeCaster is right, from the first screenshot it looks like you never installed the Desktop Development workload.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes this was the thing! Thanks a lot for pointing out my silly mistake

Comment: @Jeremy I don't think VS2017 asks that anymore? I've installed it on three machines now and don't remember being asked what language or role it should be configured for.

Comment: @CodeCaster I installed it the other day, it still asks you your preferred settings (on first open for the user profile) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 setup allows you to very fine-grainedly install various "components" separately, or groups of components delivered as "workloads".

You're missing the workload named ".NET desktop development", which contains among others these project templates. So re-run setup and install that workload.

Comment: is there any way to install the templates without the baggage which comes with workloads? For example, .netcore workload has SQL, ASP and other things I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

You have a link, Open Visual Studio Installer in a New Project window that will allow you modify your installed components